# Full Virtualization or Para Virtualization

Tags: cloud, virtualization

For cloud computing platforms providing managed services to their customers, what is more suited: Full Virtualization or Para Virtualization? and Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the requirements:

**Para Virtualization:**

- Needs the guest OS to be hacked.
- Better performance
- Support for specific OSes.

**Full Virtualization**

- Can use the OS as it is (untouched).
- Lower performance because of emulating privileged instruction (Those that trap if the processor is in user mode).
- Support for mostly any OS

So, regarding your need, you should use the one that fits your needs.

Comment: How do you define "Managed services"?

Comment: The Dr. himself doesn't say anything when I asked him about that!